# Random geometric distribution across numbers

Tags: python-3.x, random, distribution

I would like to know whether it is possible to generate random numbers following a geometric distribution, but within a list of numbers.

Suppose I have a list such as:

```
a = [2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6]
```

I would like to generate 81 values randomly, maintaining a p-value of .3.

I tried to use the following:

```
z = np.random.geometric(p=0.3, size=81)
```

But how can I draw only from a specific list of numbers?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details about what you're looking for, because whatever it is, it' ain't geometric because you're requesting a bounded range.  If you're thinking of a geometric as a starting point, you need to tell us where the unused probability goes.  Does it all get pile onto the first outcome, the last outcome, the third one from the left? Does it get distributed evenly amongst the candidates?  Do you continue the geometric decay of probabilities but loop back to the beginning?  Your question is not answerable as written.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was reading a paper and the authors mention this: "Each trial starts with a gray fixation dot lasting for a variable amount of time. The duration of the fixation dot is chosen from a geometric distribution (p=0.3; 2000–6000 ms, in steps of 500 ms)". What I was trying to do, was to replicate this procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would call it impossible, [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) is unbound.

You could do something like

```
import numpy as np

p = 0.3
a = [2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6]

q = np.random.geometric(p, size = 81) - 1
t = [a[k] for k in q]

print(t)
```

but it will sometimes throw IndexError exception.

You might think about putting upper bounds on index and build probabilities yourself, along the lines

```
# build normalized geometric-like probabilities
prb = np.asarray([p*(1.0-p)**k for k in range(0, len(a))])
prb /= np.sum(prb)

result = np.random.choice(a, size=81, replace = True, p=prb)

print(result)
```

Comment: Dear Severin, thank you very much. I am trying it out and so far it seems to work. 

I only added a while loop so that the index error will not have any impact.

Comment: @giorgio-p Glad to hear, if it works, please accept the answer and let's move on

Comment: Changing the `p`  from 0.03 to 0.3 makes a huge difference.  The probability of getting a value > 9, the number of indices you have, is ~2E-5.  Consequently you could either normalize the probabilities as @SeverinPappadeux proposes, or just generate indices to the array as `Geom(p) - 1` with rejection and a retry for indices > 8.  The rejection would only occur two times out of 10k on average.